# Vercel Deployment: Internal Server Error when updating NPM Packages

Tags: npm, deployment, nuxt.js, package.json, vercel

I'm currently working on a NUXT 2.x App and I'm hosting the dev Project on Vercel. Now since the NPM packages are outdated and I want to remove some of the packages, the Deployed Version on Vercel throws an empty page with 500 error. If i stash the changes in package.json, everything works fine on the deployed version.

How can I update / remove NPM packages from my current Version and deploy it on Vercel?

Comment: Sorry no, I had to downgrade the Firebase Version from 9.5 to 9.1, then it worked fine. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I had to downgrade the Firebase Version from 9.5 to 9.1, then it deployed just fine on Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend the usage of `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` to get a list of all the package and the possible updates.
If you want to remove a specific one, go for `yarn remove my-not-so-cool-package`.

Think about bumping your Node.js version to 14 and try to build locally before pushing to Vercel.

Then, it comes down to reading out the differences that you may have between the versions of the packages and fix the breaking changes if any.
Can't help more without more info from your part.